# Error debugging in thread memory. ex: 0x1125e404b <+1114> movl

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I apologize if this is an answer that can be easily found online. I tried searching but probably I do not know the right terminology.

Sometimes xcode gives errors like in this screenshot.

[image: xcode error]

Now in this specific case we can see that it's a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error which means that the application can't access this specific block of memory. Most likely because the code is sending a message to an object that has already been released.

What I'm missing is a more detailed summary of the screenshot. I have some assumptions about how to read it.

**line 298:**

```
0x1125e404b //Address in memory?
<+1114> //size?
movl = //... ?
%edx, (%rax) = //....?
```

Would really appreciate if anybody could point me to the right documentation or explain it here.

Also, is there a practical use for it? Perhaps inspecting the referenced block of memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a disassembly of the machine code that was executing when the crash occurred. I used to do a lot of assembler but haven't tried to work with ARM on iOS devices, but I'll give you an idea:

The first number is the absolute address in memory of the code that's executing.
The second number (I think) is the offset from the begging of the function. This is useful in tying machine code to the source code it was built from.

The next bit, `movl`, is the machine instruction, a move of a longword. It looks like it's moving a value from the edx register to a memory address pointed to by rax. (I don't know the ARM register notation so I'm doing a little guessing.

The crash likely occurs because the value in `rax` is not an accessible address.

Figuring out what it means is harder. You'd have to trace back to the beginning of the function and figure out how the different registers are used and where the value in `rax` comes from. To do that you'd need to study ARM assembler and the parameter passing conventions the compiler uses.

It's probably not worth the effort. Better to analyze your source code and figure out what's going on.

Comment: I should qualify my "it's not worth the effort". Understanding ARM and the inner workings of the machine is well worth the effort, but it is a huge undertaking that takes a big investment of time.